# Modified CSS Drop down menu code

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, navigation

Can anyone point me to a simple CSS drop-down menu code? Everything i seem to find is very overactive in the formatting department, and generally a horizontal list, which is not what i want.

[image]

This is my Navbar, i want the last 5 links (clothing, art prints, giclee, films, deals) to drop down from when hovering over the "gallery" link and disappear when onmouseout. Basically to roll out vertically from the word "gallery". These are all hashchange links, formatted by a class and paragraph ids.

Can anyone help with a simple enough code to achieve this? Some webkit effects never hurt anyone too..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/TSL3p/1/)

I have added two dropdowns in the demo, for "About" and "Products". Below is the HTML and CSS used

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="">C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">New</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Products</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="">C</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:0;
}
ul > li{
    position:relative;
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:lightgreen;
}

ul > li > a{
    font-size:20px;
}

ul ul{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    padding:5px 10px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    z-index:2;
    list-style:none;
}



ul ul a{
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple drop-down via css [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BHLF9/1/)

```
ul, li{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul{
    width: 100px;
}
li{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
li a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:1px solid red;
}
li ul{
    display: none;

}
li ul li a{
    border:none;
}
li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}


<ul>
    <li>
        <a>Link One</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Sub link One</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sub link two</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sub link three</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sub link four</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <li>
        <a>Link Two</a>
    </li>
        <li>
        <a>Link three</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Sub link One</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sub link two</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sub link three</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Sub link four</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```